# How to implement reusable component input in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

could anyone can give me a hint about reusable component input in vue 3? Like this in React:

Let say,

1. use `<Input />` reusable component in parent component

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Input from './component/Input';

function Home() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(email, password);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input id="email" labelText="Email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <Input id="password" labelText="Password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

2. here `<Input />` component:

```js
export default function Input(props) {
  const { id, labelText, value, onChange } = props;

  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>{labelText}<label>
    <input id={id} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read up on [*Component Basics* from the Vue 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#listening-to-child-components-events).

**Key concepts:**

- Use the [`v-bind`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind) directive (or `:` prefix for shorthand) for data binding
- Use the [`v-on`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on) directive (or `@` prefix for shorthand) for event handlers
- Use [double curly brackets](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#interpolations) for string interpolation of data properties
- Use the [`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-model) directive for two-way data binding
- Use [`props`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#props) option to declare properties
- Use [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) to create data properties using [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#composition-api)

The equivalent input component in Vue 3:

```html
<template>
  <label :for="id">{{ labelText }}</label>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    :id="id"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: String,
    labelText: String,
    modelValue: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

And the form:

```html
<template>
  <form @submit="handleSubmit">
    <MyInput id="email" labelText="Email" v-model="email" />
    <MyInput id="password" labelText="Password" v-model="password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import MyInput from "@/components/MyInput.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyInput,
  },
  setup() {
    const email = ref("");
    const password = ref("");

    return {
      email,
      password,
      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("submit", email.value, password.value);
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-moon-gjmls?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue)

Answer (score 1):

2023 update Using the Vue composition API (recommended way):

```
   // MyInput.js
    <template>
    <label :for="id"> {{ label }} </label>
    <input 
       :id="id" 
       :value="modelValue" 
       type="text" 
       @input="$event => emit('update:modelValue',   
       $event.target.value)" :placeholder="placeholder"
     />
    </template>

   <script  setup>
    defineProps(['modelValue', 'label', 'id', 'placeholder'])
    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
   </script>
```

and you use it like this in Vue 3 component:

```
   <template>
    <Input id="my-id" label="my label" 
        v-model="myInputValue" />
   <template>
   <script setup>
    const myInputValue = ref('')
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

New approach
how to use v-model in a reusable input component with defineModel **Vue 3.4**;
[more details on the Medium](https://medium.com/@leonidshvab1996/reusable-input-component-vue-3-c8778c1e3106)

```
// How to define the component (native HTML) 
// components/VInput.vue
<script setup>
const model = defineModel()
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="model" />
</template>

/* ***** */
// How to use the component (native HTML)
// App.vue
<VInput v-model="userName" />
```

If you use previous versions of vue.js (more old), you can try to use [macro define-models](https://vue-macros.dev/macros/define-models.html) or use solutions described in other answers

Answer (score 0):

I have created a form input component that offers more features with less code.

```
<template>
  <div class="mb-6">
    <!-- form label -->

    <!-- 
      I have included default classes in this code which can be overwritten if you add a new class. For instance, the default class is "text-red-500". If you add a class to the parent element, only this class will be overwritten, while the other classes will remain in their default state.
    -->

    <!-- If the parent element does not have a label, the label for the input tag will be automatically hidden. -->
    <label
      v-if="label.value !== ''"
      :for="id"
      :class="[labelClass, 'block mb-2 text-md font-medium text-red-500']"
    >
      {{ label }}
    </label>

    <!-- form input -->

    <!-- 
      I have included default classes in this code which can be overwritten if you add a new class. For instance, the default class is "bg-gray-300". If you add a class to the parent element, only this class will be overwritten, while the other classes will remain in their default state.
    -->
    <input
      :id="id"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :class="[
        'block',
        'bg-gray-50',
        'border',
        'border-gray-300',
        'text-gray-900',
        'text-md',
        'font-medium',
        'rounded-lg',
        'focus:outline-red-500',
        'block',
        'w-full',
        'p-2.5',
      ]"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    default: "input",
  },

  //classes for form label
  labelClass: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
});
</script>
```

You can use it like this.

```
<FormInputMedium
  id="email"
  v-model="email"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter your email"
  required=""
  class="text-md"
  label="Your Email"
  labelClass="text-blue-500"
 />
```